# Image displays when choosing from gallery but not when capturing from camera

Tags: java, android

On the press of a button, `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` lets the user choose between taking a picture or choosing one from the gallery four times. These  four URIs are stored in an ArrayList and the four should be shown in their respective ImageViews. The problem I'm having is that when I "capture a picture", it doesn't show in the ImageView right away; but the pictures I chose from gallery do.

The picture I captured is properly saved and can be found in "choose from gallery" the next time I press the button. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

takePictureIntent():

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("error","IOException");
            }catch (NullPointerException nullEx) {
                Log.w("error","NullPointerException");
            }
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }
            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            if(id.equals(HAPPY_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SURPRISED_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(AFRAID_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(UPSET_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SAD_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO ||
                    requestCode == REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }
                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
                //Log.d("doing ids", "right before id");
                //Log.d("doing ids", "id is " + id);
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in happy");
                    happyList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    surprisedList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    afraidList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    upsetList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    sadList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this works for me

```
public Uri captureImage() {
    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (chooserIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image File name");
        Uri takenImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, takenImageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intentPicture, MyConstants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        return takenImageUri;
    }
    return null;
}


public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri){
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MyConstants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                if (takenImageUri != null) {
                    Uri imagePath =getRealPathFromURI(takenImageUri,this));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This allows user to choose between taking or choosing pictures?

Answer (score 0):

rather than looping for 4 times, why not make each imageView an OnClickListener to get the image one by one?

Comment: I appreciate the idea! But the scenario I outlined in my question is representing something similar to what I'm actually doing in my activity. The functionality is essentially the same so an answer to this question will help me with my actual situation.